# Proving Equivalence Relations by providing an example based on given subsets.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $X$ be the set of all nonempty subsets of $\{1, 2, 3\}$. Then

$X= \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$

Define a relation $ R $ on $X$ as follows: For all $A$ and $B$ in $X$,

$A \, R\, B\Leftrightarrow$ the least element of $A$ equals the least element of $B$ .

Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.

The solution is:

$R$ is reflexive: Suppose $A$ is a nonempty subset of $\{1, 2, 3\}$. [We must show that $A \, R \, A,$ It is true to say that the least element of $ A$ equals the least element of $A$. Thus, by definition of $R$, $A \, R \, A$. (There is more, and the answers are proving the Symmetric and Transitive...But I just want to know the examples. I can connect the dots once I find an example based on proving the reflexive property of equivalence relations on this set).

My question is, what is this least element they are speaking of? Can someone give the least element based on the subsets. Thank you so very much.

Comment: We know that $1<2<3$,so we define the least element of A to be $0$ if $1,2,3$ are all not in A(or A is empty), $1$ if $1$ is in A, 2 if $1$ isn't in A and $2$ is in A, and $3$ in all other situations. That's all, now you can go out and prove your assertion.

Comment: 0 isn't necessary above, anything smaller than 1 will do.

Comment: @ abdefghijklmnopqrtxyz-s too wouldn't 1 be the smallest in this case? Thanks I really appreciate you answering friend.

Comment: @abdefghijklmnopqrtxyz-stoo The "least element" is typically defined only for non-empty sets (whence the hypothesis). For instance, we say that a set is well-ordered if "every non-epty subset has a leas element". Sometimes, in real analysis, one defines $\inf\emptyset=-\infty$, but it's not the case here (and it's an $\inf$, not a "least element").

Comment: @ G. Sassatelli Thank you so much for answering. so, 1 is the least element in this case right? Or do they mean the subset with the least element, such as {1}, {2}, and {3}?

Comment: @ G. Sassatelli so what would be the least element here in this case?

Comment: @gordonsung The ordering is on elements. Allow me to call the $\min S$ the least element of the subset $S$. Then $$\min\{1,2\}=1,\ \min\{2\}=2,\ \min\{1,2,3\}=1$$

Comment: Thank you so much  G. Sassatelli. Can you submit your answer so I can mark you as helpful/ give you credit (copy and paste this answer on to the submit box so I can give you credit)? Thank you so very much

Comment: @abcdefghijklmnopqrtxyz-stoo I made a small mistake in my comment: we sometimes define $\inf \emptyset=+\infty $, but basically the observation stands.

Comment: You're right, it stands. I'll vote up your comment. Thanks  for helping me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-doubting the assignment. The ordering is just the one of natural numbers restricted to the subset $\{1,2,3\}$, i.e. $1<2<3$. The "least element of a subset $S$" (allow me to call it $\min S$) is a proper element of $S$, not a singleton. Then, for instance $$\min\{1,2\}=1,\ \min\{2\}=2,\ \min\{1,2,3\}=1$$

**Insight on the problem:** To simplify the proof, you may notice that $$A \ R\ B\iff \min A=\min B$$ $\min$ is a function assigning to each $A\in\mathcal P(\{1,2,3\})\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ a value (in this case, an element of $\{1,2,3\}$). It is a general fact that, if $\mathcal R$ is a relation on $X$ and there exists a function $f:X\to Y$ such that $x_1\mathcal R x_2\iff f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then $\mathcal R$ is an equivalence relation. The converse holds as well: if $\mathcal R$ is an equivalence relation on a set $X$, there exists a set $Y$ and a function $f:X\to Y$ such that $x_1\mathcal R x_2\iff f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. In general, though, $Y$ is not required to be a subset of $X$.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks

Comment: Great answer. Would love to write like this sometime.